# Basic ASyncTask assistance

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Okay, I've read the Android documentation and been perusing article after article on ASyncTask and just don't understand how to get information back from my external ASyncTask class. This runs fine:

```
    myASyncTask = new MyASyncTask();
    myASyncTask.execute(myParam);
```

...and I fully expect the task to complete but how do I get anything back from it? The documentation says that onPostExecute is invoked on the UI thread but it also says to not call onPostExecute manually?!? How do I get data back from my ASyncTask object???

I've got it to work fine when I create my ASyncTask as an inner class but I'd rather this task be external so I can call it from different Activitys.

Comment: Well I worked it out. Turns out using the`ASyncTask` `get()` and `getStatus()` methods are the way to go. `getStatus` gives you a progress update and `get` gives you the end product of `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) you can use `get` method to get the result , and it waits till the task is done .

You can also use [`getStatus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) to get the current status of the task , assuming it publishes it .